# Storing an html-table in an array in Java.

Tags: java, html, arrays

My assignment is to read an html-file and filter out all html-tags and only store the values (that are integers) in an array. I'm only allowed to use the Scanner and its methods. I've been googling and found suggestions about using .replace or some existing functions that easily removes all html-tags, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use it.

This is what I've done so far. Each table start with a line of "00-01", "01-02", "02-03" and so on. I use this as a delimiter and the code below is only printing the html-code between 2 tables.

```
public static void getEightDays(int[][] data) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(nordpoolURL);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    while (scan.findInLine("00-01") == null) {
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    while (scan.findInLine("01-02") == null) {
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
    }

}
```

It gives me the following;

```
</td>
<td align="right"> 11872</td>
<td align="right"> 12146</td>
<td align="right"> 12861</td>
<td align="right"> 12561</td>
<td align="right"> 13493</td>
<td align="right"> 13386</td>
<td align="right"> 12732</td>
<td align="right"> <b>12249</b></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
```

[Here's the full html-code of the website I'm trying to read.](http://view-source:http://wwwdynamic.nordpoolspot.com/marketinfo/consumption/sweden/consumption.cgi?interval=last8)

To summarize, my problem is that I can't find a way to get rid of all the html-tags by only using methods of Scanner. Also, with my way of doing it I'd have to have 24 while-loops since there are 24 rows of data and that just seems inefficient and that there's probably an easier way of doing this.

Please help me by pointing me in the right direction! Thank you.

Comment: Assignment, you say? Limited to only the scanner methods? People here on SO won't take too kindly to homework questions, FYI.

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for someone to solve my assignment. I'm simply looking for some guidance or ideas on how I can do this.